# Walk through on setting up a Server 2008 VPS?

Tags: windows-server-2008, vps

I'm a developer, who wanted a small VPS to use instead of a shared host. I don't deal much with the IT side of things.

So far, I've purchased a VPS from Thrust and installed 2008 on it.

I enabled updates, and set it to the Web Server Role.

Now, I'd like to use it as its own DNS server (so that is is easy to manage sub domains directly), but I'm not sure where to start... Install AD? Setup DNS?

This is all foreign to me, I'm used to just giving builds to the SA guys :)

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your actual question, you just need to install the DNS server role, you do not need AD (unless you want to actually use Active Directory for things, but I doubt it). Once installed you can use the DNS mmc to create and edit your DNS zones.

That said, if you are going to be using this server for commercial purposes,  I would suggest either looking at getting a professional to look at it, or spend some time learning about Windows administration, especially how to secure your server.